# asciidoc cross reference to a document in a directory on the same level

Tags: asciidoc, asciidoctor

I have an `asciidoc` documentation structure like this:

```
src/docs/rep1/doc1.adoc
src/docs/rep2/doc2.adoc
```

I'm trying to create a cross reference from `doc1` to `doc2`.

I tried something like:

```
have a look to <<../rep2/doc2.adoc#title,document 2>>
```

but it doesn't work, can somebody hint what is wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: That should work, if it doesn't please submit a bug in asciidoctor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known issue of version 1.5.2:
[#844: Allow path for inter-document cross reference (xref) to begin with path segment](https://github.com/asciidoctor/asciidoctor/issues/844)

The current workaround for this is to do something like that:

```
have a look to <<fake/../../rep2/doc2.adoc#title,document 2>>
```